# Optional search inputs with SQL query

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller

Could someone please assist / advise on what I could do in order to make the last four search fields / inputs optional (along with AND statements) in the SQL query?

I have tried the code below but it doesn't seem to make the last four fields optional:

```
  public static function findBySearch($location, $category, $type, $bedrooms, $bathrooms, $minamount, $maxamount)
    {
        $db = static::getDB();
         
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts
         WHERE location = :location
         AND category LIKE :category
         AND type LIKE :type
         AND 
         (:bedrooms IS NULL OR bedrooms = :bedrooms)
         AND 
         (:bathrooms IS NULL OR bathrooms = :bathrooms)
         AND 
         (:minamount IS NULL OR amount >= :minamount)
         AND 
         (:maxamount IS NULL OR amount <= :maxamount)';
          
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 

            $stmt->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':bedrooms', $bedrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':bathrooms', $bathrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':minamount', $minamount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':maxamount', $maxamount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  
            $stmt->execute();  
                
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());

            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: Optional in the sense of sometimes you won't be supplying them at all?

Comment: That's because you're trying to bind the column name for NULL instead of actually using the column name. `:minamount` will not be null

Comment: What you need to do is selectively build your query so that it only searches those columns if supplied

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes, not filling anything in those fields.

Comment: @aynber Thank you for the reply. Could you perhaps please advise on how I could selectively build the query?

Comment: Query is nothing more than a string. All you need to do is check if a filter value is supplied and if it is, then add one more piece to the query string. Same goes for value binding - you only bind if a parameter is supplied.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank you for the information. Could you please advise on whether you suggest that I use If statements inside the query?

Comment: PHP `if`s that concatenate to the query for every parameter that is specified.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Could you perhaps please assist with an example of a If statement that I could use?